# my css result in ipad 2 doesn't work well

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I have my result in Windows PC like this:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hqaa.png), and everything is fine.

My piece of css code is like this:

```
.colkiri{
    display: table-cell;
    border-left: 1px solid #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
    min-width: 20px;
}
```

But, if i open it in my IPAD 2, it looks like this: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJXG6.png). It's like the border-left **none**, not **solid** anymore, whereas i don't change anything in my code. Why?

My fully css (admintree.css):

```
#boxpost{
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
}
#commentleftside{
    margin-left:10
}
#bigbox{
    width: auto;
    display: table;
}
.nomorver{
    color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: verdana; /*nempel tulisannya*/
    word-spacing: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 40px;
}
.colkiri{
    display: table-cell;
    border-left: 1px none #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
    min-width: 20px;
}
.colkanan{
    display: table-cell;
}
.colkananchild{
    border-left: 1px solid #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
    float: left;
}
#username{
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
#username:before{
    content:" \00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a";
    text-decoration:line-through;
    color: #FEBA0E;
}
.usernamechild{
    color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: verdana; /*nempel tulisannya*/
    word-spacing: 15px;
}
.usernamechild a {
    color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
    text-decoration: none;
}
.usernamechild a:hover {
    color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
    text-decoration: underline;
    mouse: pointer;
}
.note{
    color: #888;
    font-size: x-small;
    font: normal x-small verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}
.joinunder{
    color: #FFFF00;
    font-size: x-small;
    font: normal x-small verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: red;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.joinunder a {
    color: #FFFF00; /*biru gelap*/
    text-decoration: none;
}
.joinunder a:hover {
    color: #FFFF00; /*biru gelap*/
    text-decoration: underline;
    mouse: pointer;
}
```

and my fully HTML:

```
<?php
    include('sbmcon.php');
    include('logincheckadmin.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Tree</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/sbmico.ico">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/admintree.css'>
    <style>
        .umpetin{
            margin-left:50px;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        .borderred{
            border:2px solid red;
            padding-left: 2px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }
        .bordergreen{
            border:2px solid green;
            padding-left: 2px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pujoinunder(pageURL, title, w, h) {
            var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
            var top = (screen.height - h) / 2;  // for 25% - devide by 4  |  for 33% - devide by 3
            var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        } 
        function pudelrec(pageURL, title, w, h) {
            var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
            var top = (screen.height - h) / 2;  // for 25% - devide by 4  |  for 33% - devide by 3
            var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        } 
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ctrljs">
<?php
    $page=isset($_REQUEST['page'])?$_REQUEST['page']:null;
    $ssloginadmin=$_SESSION['ssloginadmin'];
    $qitungitung=mysql_query("SELECT a.cv AS CountVer, a.mv AS MaxVer, a.cv-a.mv AS selisih FROM
                              (SELECT COUNT(ver) AS cv, MAX(ver) AS mv FROM t_un WHERE upgrade='1') a");
    $fitungitung=mysql_fetch_object($qitungitung);
    if($fitungitung->selisih<>0){
        $msgitungitung="<span class='borderred'><font color='red'><strong>pohon rusak (please press fixver and fixtcount)</font></span>";
    }else{
        $msgitungitung="<span class='bordergreen'><font color='green'><strong>pohon bagus</strong></font></span>";
    }
    echo "
        <a href='?page=fixver' style='text-decoration: none' ><input type='button' value='fix ver'></input></a>
        <a href='?page=fixtcount' style='text-decoration: none' ><input type='button' value='fix tcount'></input></a>
        <button type='button' onclick=\"javascript:putreeadd('treeadd.php?start=yes','test',400,250)\">add</button>
        <button type='button' onclick=\"javascript:pudelrec('admintreedelrec.php?page=form','test',400,250)\"><font color='red'>Delete Multiple Record</font></button>
        <a href='treefilter.php?start=yes' style='text-decoration: none' target='_blank'><input type='button' value='filter'></input></a>
        <br>
        CountVer=$fitungitung->CountVer, MaxVer=$fitungitung->MaxVer, Selisih=$fitungitung->selisih, berarti=$msgitungitung
    ";

    //executed
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT ai,ver,hor,t,username,namealias,city,sponsor,upline,sponsorcount,sponsorcounttree,t1name,t2name,t1count,t2count,email,mlmid,hp,bb,ve,status,upgrade FROM t_un WHERE upgrade='1' ORDER BY ver,t");
    while($f=mysql_fetch_object($q)){
        echo "
            <div id='bigbox'><span class='nomorver' nowrap>$f->ver.</span>
        ";
        for($a=1;$a<=$f->hor-1;$a++){
            echo "
                <div class='colkiri'></div>
            ";
        }
        echo "
                <div class='colkanan'>
                    <div class='colkananchild'>
                        <div id='username'> 
                            <span class='usernamechild'>$f->username</span>
        ";
                            if($f->t1count==0 || $f->t2count==0){
                                echo "<span class='joinunder'><a href='#formjoin$f->ver' onclick=\"javascript:pujoinunder('admintreeupgrade.php?page=form&un=$f->username','test',400,250)\">join under</a></span> ";
                            }
                            if($f->t1count==0 && $f->t2count==0){
                                echo "<span class='joinunder'><a href='?page=delrec&un=$f->username' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">x</a></span> ";
                            }
        echo "
                            <span class='note'>hor=$f->hor, t=$f->t, email=$f->email, ".($f->mlmid=="none"?"<span class='joinunder'>IDC2G=$f->mlmid</span>":"IDC2G=$f->mlmid").", <font color='red'>sponsor=</font>$f->sponsor, <font color='blue'>upline=</font>$f->upline, t1name=$f->t1name, t2name=$f->t2name, <font color='red'>sponsorcount=</font>$f->sponsorcount, <font color='red'>sponsorcounttree=</font>$f->sponsorcounttree, t1count=$f->t1count, t2count=$f->t2count, <font color='red'>ve=</font>$f->ve, <font color='red'>upgrade=</font>$f->upgrade
                            <!--
                            <div class='umpetin' id='formjoin$f->ver' style='display:none;'>
                                <iframe style='border: 1px solid #FEBA0E; padding: 5px' src='admintreeupgrade.php?page=form&un=$f->username' width='400px' height='205px'></iframe>
                            </div>
                            -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ";
    }
    echo "
        </div>
    ";
    if($page=='fixver'){
        fixver();
    }
    if($page=='fixtcount'){
        fixtcount();
    }
    if($page=='delrec'){
        $un=isset($_REQUEST['un'])?$_REQUEST['un']:null;
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM t_un WHERE username='$un'");
        fixver();
        fixtcount();
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='admintree.php'</script>";
    }
    $submit=isset($_REQUEST['submit'])?$_REQUEST['submit']:null;
    if($submit=='yes'){
        $cl=isset($_REQUEST['cl'])?$_REQUEST['cl']:null;
        $arrayid = implode(', ',$cl);
        mysql_query("UPDATE t_un SET mw='1' WHERE ai IN(".$arrayid.")");
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='admintree.php'</script>";
    }
    $signout=isset($_REQUEST['signout'])?$_REQUEST['signout']:null;
    if($signout=='yes'){
        unset($_SESSION['ssloginadmin']);
        unset($ssloginadmin);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'http://sbm.website'</script>";
    }
    function fixver(){
        //blocking, jika sedang ada proses
        $q6=mysql_query("SELECT status FROM t_process");
        $f6=mysql_fetch_object($q6);
        if($f6->status=='yes'){
            echo "
                <center>
                <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <h3><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Wait....</h3>
                    Someone is processing , try again in a few second, thank you.
                </div>
                <button type='button' onclick=\"history.back();\" class='btn btn-danger'>back</button>
                </center>
            ";
            exit;
        }
        //start
        mysql_query("UPDATE t_process SET status='yes'");

        $n=0;
        $q2=mysql_query("SELECT ver,username FROM t_un WHERE upgrade='1' ORDER BY ver");
        while($f2=mysql_fetch_object($q2)){
            $count++;
            mysql_query("UPDATE t_un SET ver='$count' WHERE username='$f2->username'");
        }

        //finish
        mysql_query("UPDATE t_process SET status='no'");
        echo "<script language=javascript> alert('Fix Ver done')</script>"; 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='admintree.php'</script>";
        //echo "fixver ready";
    }
    function fixtcount(){
        mysql_query("UPDATE t_process SET status='1'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE t_un SET t1count='0',t2count='0',t1name=null,t2name=null");
        $q2=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM t_un WHERE upgrade='1' ORDER BY ver DESC");
        while($f2=mysql_fetch_object($q2)){
            $simpanupline=$f2->username;
            do {
                //penghitungan upline nomor 2 dan seterusnya keatas
                $simpanupline2=$simpanupline;
                $q=mysql_query("SELECT upline,t FROM t_un WHERE username='$simpanupline2'");
                $f=mysql_fetch_object($q);
                $simpanupline=trim($f->upline);
                $simpanT=$f->t;
                mysql_query("UPDATE t_un SET t$simpanT".'count'."=t$simpanT".'count'."+1, t$simpanT".'name'."='$simpanupline2' WHERE username='$simpanupline'");
            } while($simpanupline2<>'sbm');
        }
        mysql_query("UPDATE t_process SET status='0'");
        echo "<script language=javascript> alert('Fix Tcount done')</script>"; 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='admintree.php'</script>";
        //echo "fixtcount ready";
    }
?>
<script>
    $('.joinunder').click(function(){
        var divToToggle = $($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
        divToToggle.slideToggle('slow');
        $('.umpetin:visible').not(divToToggle).hide('slow');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the markup, could we please see your HTML and a fully working example?

Comment: fully? ok, wait a minute

Comment: @hungerstar. that was my fully css and a piece of html

Comment: Could you please supply the rendered HTML, that is no PHP just what it looks like when you view source? Thanks.

Comment: ok2, i give my fully HTML, wait a minute.

Comment: @hungerstar. That was my fully code.

Comment: You're still providing the PHP/HTML mix. Please provide the rendered HTML, thank you. The rendered HTML will be what you see when you select _View Source_ in a web browser.

Comment: Hi Juna, open this page in a desktop Chrome browser, go to FILE > SAVE PAGE AS. Save it as HTML and post it on here for us to help you.